# How to enter a folder without knowing its name?

Tags: c#, text-files

I need to read a text file that I know its full path, except one folder's name. I' d use

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path + "\\" + unknownFolderName + "\\" + itemName);
```

but first, I need to find out *unknownFolderName* to reach the file' s full path. There is exactly one folder under *path*, all I need to do is entering under this folder, without knowing its name. How can I achieve this in simplest way?

Comment: How can you NOT know the folder's name? The file-system is aware of all files and folders. Iterate through them until you find your text-file.

Comment: This line is used inside a loop, so that I am not certain what the folder' s name will be. That' s why I can' t hardcode it.

Comment: Then you seem to have issues with your code; .NET provides functionality to search the local file-system and if you don't know what you are looking for you can't find it...

Comment: Could you post the code block in its entirety?  There may be another more obvious solution and what we're looking at here is an [xy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [Directory.GetDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx). If you're guaranteed to only have one folder underneath that folder, then you should be able to do it VIA:

```
string unknownPath = Directory.GetDirectories(path)[0];
//Now instead of this: [ string readText = File.ReadAllText(path + "\\" + unknownFolderName + "\\" + itemName) ], do this:
string readText = File.ReadAllText(unknownPath + "\\" + itemName);
```

That should do it. Let me know if it works out for you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Directory.GetDirectories` static method ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx)) which returns the array of strings - full paths to the direcotries in the path you passed to the method. So try something like this (if you are sure that there is at least one directory and you want to use the first one):

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetDirectories(path)[0] + "\\" + itemName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. just a misspelling: `Directories.GetDirectories()` -> `Directory.GetDirectories()`

Comment: @Alpay Sorry for the misspelling, I don't know what I was thinking, wrote it from the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

**In case you have more than one folder, and you don't know which one is**:

Take a look at the following example. You're looking for `Windows` in the following path: `C:\_____\System32\notepad.exe`

```
string path = @"C:\";
var itemName = @"System32\notepad.exe";

var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

foreach (var dir in directories) {
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(dir, itemName);

    //If you found the correct directory!
    if (File.Exists(fullPath)) {
        Console.WriteLine(fullPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the folder names under your directory:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4359/listing-files-folders-in-a-directory/